# Full URL with url_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get a full url in rails?

url_for @book is returning only a path like /book/1 and not www.domain.com/book/1

Thanks (and sorry if the answer is obvious. Im learning rails!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the :host option.  For example, you can use:

```
url_for(@book, :host => "domain.com")
```

Note: with Rails 3 and above, use `polymorphic_url` instead of `url_for`.

Comment: I don't think this is supported in Rails 3 - might be better to use polymorphic_url

Comment: This does not work with the latest releases of Rails (> 3.2 and maybe even 3.1). url_for accepts only one argument, which can be either a string, an instance of a model, or a hash of options.

Comment: In rails 4 `url_for` calls `polymorphic_url`.

Comment: Here's a link to `polymorphic_url` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

I used it with an object like so `polymorphic_url(object, subdomain: "something")`

Answer (score 67):

According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000455), this shouldn't happen. The option you're looking for is `:only_path` and it's false by default. What happens if you set it to false explicitly?

```
url_for(@book, :only_path => false)
```

While you can use `url_for` you should prefer Ryan's method when you can - `book_url(@book)` for a full url or `book_path(@book)` for the path.

Comment: Adding :only_path => false solved it for me using rails 3.1.1

Comment: url_for(@book, :only_path => false) raises an exception here because you've passed in 2 arguments when its expecting 1. Seems like they would build this method to accept options, but in the latest versions of rails it accepts only one: either a string/instance or a hash of options.

Comment: ```link_to(@book.title, book_path(@book, only_path: false))``` worked for me (Rails 3)

Comment: This says that :only_path is true by default.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Comment: @amoose In Rails 4, it is possible to pass the the hash and more arguments though an array, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25633769/895245).

Comment: Worked perfectly for what I needed : `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="<%= url_for(locale: 'en'.to_s, only_path: false) %>">`. Note that now you can use the option key column suffixed notation rather thar prefixing it and using `=>`.

Comment: How do you get a url if it's a subdomain? `polymorphic_url` always returns the `domain.com` in my situation not `sub.domain.com` which is what I want.

Answer (score 23):

If it's a RESTful resource you'll be able to use this:

```
book_url(@book)
```

Comment: `url_for` is DRYer as it does not duplicate which model you are talking about, automatically taking care of polymorphism.

Answer (score 16):

In Rails 4, **[url_for only takes one argument](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for)**, so you need to pass an array with an explicit hash inside for the `only_path` option.

Good:

```
url_for([@post, @comment, {only_path: true}])
```

Bad:

```
url_for(@post, @comment, {only_path: true})
url_for([@post, @comment], {only_path: true})
```

From the source, `url_for` with an `Array` input just calls:

```
polymorphic_url([@post, @comment], {only_path: true})
```

as shown in @moose's answer.

As noted by @lime, `only_path` is generally not needed for `polymorphic_url` since you distinguish that with the `_url` `_path` suffixes.

Comment: This instead gives me a `#<NoMethodError: undefined method \`model_name' for Hash:Class>`... Will investigate.

Comment: @lime weird, it seemed to work on my tests and I pushed it to gitlab: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/652f4c8090793de4737b904b5feb11c27424f4c5/app/views/notify/_reassigned_issuable_email.text.erb#L3 Let me know if you find something.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using `polymorphic_url` directly. That way, I can pick between `_url` and `_path` in the method name instead of passing a hash. Still don't know what caused the error though.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this would work:

```
url_for(@book)
```

But it does not. The url_for method accepts only one argument, which can be either a string, an instance of a model, or a hash of options. This is rather unfortunate, as it would seem like you may need to link to @book and add options like :only_path or :host as well.

One way around it is to use polymorphic_url, which would render the correct absolute url even though your model is (likely) not actually polymorphic:

```
polymorphic_url(@book, :host => "domain.com")
```

Perhaps the best route would be to use a named route, which is set up automatically for you when declaring resources in your routes or using the :as option:

```
# in routes.rb:
resources :books
# or
get "books/:id" => "books#show", as: :book

# in your view:
book_path(@book, :host => "domain.com")
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the 'host' parameter to polymorphic_url. To get the relative path you can use polymorphic_path.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 5, if you want the full url for the current controller/action (== current page), just use:

```
url_for(only_path: false)
```

Long answer:

In Rails 5, `url_for` in a view is `ActionView::RoutingUrlFor#url_for`. If you look at it's source code (`https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for`), you'll see if you pass a Hash (keyword parameters are cast into a Hash by Ruby), it actually calls `super`, thus invoking the method of same name in it's ancestor.

`ActionView::RoutingUrlFor.ancestors` reveals that it's first ancestor is `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`.

Checking it's source code (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for), you'll read this:

> Missing routes keys may be filled in from the current request's
>   parameters (e.g. :controller, :action, :id and any other parameters
>   that are placed in the path).

This is very nice, since it will build automatically a URL for you for the current page (or path, if you just invoke `url_for` without the `only_path: false`). It will also intelligently ignore the query string params; if you need to merge those, you can use `url_for(request.params.merge({arbitrary_argument:'value'}))`.