# Rails - How To Get Full URL in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 app, I'm trying to get the full URL for my instance, but when I tried to use `url_for` as suggested in this SO question, I get an error, `NoMethodError: undefined method 'url_for' for #<Product:0x8646fc0>`.

[Full URL with url_for in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489838/full-url-with-url-for-in-rails)

```
def get_url
  url = url_for(self)
end
```

I also tried `product_url(self)` and received a similar error.

What's the proper way to get the URL for my instance?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

helper method is only available in view or decorator.
it's better to define `url` in the decorator.

if you want to use helper method in the model, try this

```
def url
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.product_url(self)
end
```

Comment: I got this to work, but had to add the host and only_path options for it to show the complete url `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.product_url(self, :only_path => false, :host => "www.foo.com")`

Comment: you can specify protocal too. like this `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.product_url(self, :host => "www.foo.com", :protocal => 'https')`

Comment: Would this work for development too or just for production?